# СПП образа действия или следствия?

Tags: синтаксис

*К полуночи он так начитался письма и так наелся роз, что **матери пришлось** взять его, как теленка, за подбородок и **заставить проглотить ложку касторового масла**.*

Я вижу выделенную часть как придаточное образа действия. Скажите пожалуйста, в нем есть что-нибудь от следствия?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Это придаточное с двумя значениями:образа действия и следствия (указательное местоименное слово ТАК, союз ЧТО).

Сравнить: Так наелся, как никогда не наедался раньше. Это придаточное только со значением образа действия (местоименная пара ТАК...КАК).

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу в этом предложении явный признак придаточного степени: начитался и наелся КАК? В КАКОЙ СТЕПЕНИ?